# Python search/replaice with readline and if else

Tags: python, string, search, file-io, replace

I am coding a simple python script that parses a text file and is looking for a string, if this string was found than will replace the string with another string and if this search string was not found than will be append a string.

I would like to some something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
import fileinput, glob, string, sys, os 
from os.path import join

myfile="textfile.txt"

search_string="pussy"
replace_string1="tutti"
replace_string2="frutti"

replace_strings = replace_string1 + '\n' + replace_string2

stext = str(search_string);
rtext = str(replace_strings);

print "finding:\n" + stext + "\n\nreplacing with:\n" + rtext + "\n\nin:\n" + myfile

for line in fileinput.input(myfile,inplace=1):
   lineno = 0 
   lineno = string.find(line, stext)
if lineno >=0:
    line = line.replace(stext, rtext)
    sys.stdout.write(line)
else:
    print "append line"
```

---

so if i use this that script will run the if statement and else! what is wrong?

Comment: You need to use the correct indentation when posting a Python question; your `if lineno >= 0` test is not even part of the `fileinput.input()` loop, and the lines preceding it use 3 spaces instead of four but later lines *do* use 4. All this make your code invalid.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the `lineno` variable? `lineno` is **always** going to be `0`, so `lineno >= 0` is always true.

Comment: Do you want to append the text to the end of the file, and only when the search text has not been found? Should *all* occurrences of the search text be replaced, or only the first one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indentation is very important in Python. Compare your code:

```
for line in fileinput.input(myfile,inplace=1):
   lineno = 0 
   lineno = string.find(line, stext)
if lineno >=0:
   line = line.replace(stext, rtext)
    sys.stdout.write(line)
else:
    print "append line"
```

with this version:

```
for line in fileinput.input(myfile,inplace=1):
    lineno = 0 
    lineno = string.find(line, stext)
    if lineno >=0:
        line = line.replace(stext, rtext)
        sys.stdout.write(line)
    else:
        print "append line"
```

See the difference? 
Your `if` whas being executed AFTER the for loop ended, with `lineno` containing it's last evaluation (apparently, your `stext` is not contained in the last line of the file..., that's all it means).

Comment: The code still won't work correctly as it'll print `append line` for any line in the input not matching the search text. The indentation is not the cause of the problem, merely an artifact of not knowing how to post here on SO yet.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters He wants the code to output `append line` for any line in the input not matching search text.

Comment: I am not so certain. The OP wrote: *if i use this that script will run the if statement and else!*, implying that he's suprised the `append line` print takes place at all even if there is a match.

Comment: I didn't interpret it that way. The goal is to replace the lines matching the `stext` and appending (that is, leave them intact) the others. I interpreted printing `append line` was some sort of control meaning "this line is ok, it doesn't contain `stext`, so I'll just append it"

Comment: Ah, the OP now has indicated that my code actually does what he wanted it to do.

Comment: Oh, now I see what you mean with `print` being redirected to the file, but why `lineno >= 0` couldn't be false? `string.find` will return `-1` on failure.

Comment: Yea, I got that last part wrong, thrown off by the variable name, but only partly. `-1` is *true*, so if the text is not found, no replacement is made. The replacement is only made if the line *starts* with the search text.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot easily append lines to the end of a file with `fileinput.input()`, as you cannot easily detect when the file has ended without finding a match. You are also using `string.find()`, which is not the best way to test if a text is present as `-1` is returned when the text is not found, which you don't correctly test for.

You'll have to re-open the file in append mode after looping over `fileinput.input()`:

```
import fileinput
import sys

myfile = "textfile.txt"

search_string = "pussy"
replace_string = "tutti\nfrutti"

found = False 
for line in fileinput.input(myfile, inplace=1):
    if search_string in line:
        found = True
    line = line.replace(search_string, replace_string)
    sys.stdout.write(line)

if not found:
    with open(myfile, 'a') as outfh:
        outfh.write(replace_string + '\n')
```

Comment: Note that you appear to have accepted Marcos' answer as correct, but your comment here seems to imply that his correction of your indentation is not what you wanted.